# Regex options matching multi-line as well as ignoring the case

Tags: c#, html, regex, multiline, ignore-case

I have some piece of ill-formed html, sometimes the " is missing. Also, it sometimes shows capital cases while other times lower cases:

```
<DIV class="main">
    <DIV class="subsection1">
   <H2>
   <DIV class=subwithoutquote>StackOverflow</DIV></H2></DIV></DIV>
```

I would like to match both multi-line and ignoring the case. But the following patern does not seem to be working. (For the concatenation, I also tried | instead of &)

```
const string pattern = @"<div class=""?main""?><div class=""?subsection1""?><h2><div class=""?subwithoutquote""?>(.+?)</div>";
Match m = Regex.Match(html, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Or should I add \n* in the pattern to solve multi-line issue?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you tried using HTML parser?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Your regex fails, since you didn't allow free whitespace between the tags `\s+`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem is that you are not allowing for white-space in your regex between tabs. The correct regex (tested in Rubular) is:

```
<div class=""?main""?>\s*<div class=""?subsection1""?>\s*<h2>\s*<div class=\"?subwithoutquote\"?>(.+?)<\/div>\s*
```

Notice the addition of several `\s*` entries.

The second problem is that you're not concatenating the options properly.

Your code:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(html, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Since these are bit flags, Bitwise-And (`&` operator) is a wrong flag. What you want is Bitwise-Or (`|` operator).

> Bitwise-And means "if the bit is set in ***both*** of these, leave it set; otherwise, unset it. You need Bitwise-Or, which means "if the bit is set in ***either*** of these, set it; otherwise, unset it."

Comment: I've edited my original post. I tried both & and | neither worked.

Comment: @Yang I've updated and corrected the regex ommission of whitespace, which fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to OR them together in this case.

```
const string pattern = @"<div class=""?main""?><div class=""?subsection1""?><h2><div class=""?subwithoutquote""?>(.+?)</div>";
Match m = Regex.Match(html, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Edit: Change your RegEx to the following ...

```
const string pattern = @"<div class="?main"?>\s*<div class="?subsection1"?>\*+<h2>\s*<div class="?subwithoutquote"?>(.+?)</div>
```