# regex.matches notmatching

Tags: c#, regex, .net-2.0

im trying to do this for 5 hours im desperate im gonna get mad. 
please helpme.

```
var start   =  new  List<string>( ) {"Report", "Audit"  , "Committee" } ;
string expresss= start[0] + @"(.*?)\n{0,1}(.*?)" + start[1] + @"(.*)$";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, "(?im)"+ expresss );
```

this code  fails to find ""REPORT OF THE AUDIT COMMITEE""

[image]

but here wit sublime text3's regex ican find it .

[image]

please help me to find  ""REPORT OF THE AUDIT COMMITEE"" via c# regex code.
thanks.

Comment: It's not something as simple as the case, is it?

Comment: Where do you create the `text` variable?

Comment: It can be because of linbreak: use `\r?\n`. Try `string expresss= start[0] + @"(.*?)\r?\n{0,1}(.*?)" + start[1] + @"(.*)$";`

Comment: thats what i did . it gives same resul before .    start[0] + @"(.*?)\r?\n{0,1}(.*?)" + start[1] + @"(.*)$"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex options matching multi-line as well as ignoring the case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611495/regex-options-matching-multi-line-as-well-as-ignoring-the-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's both the fact that it's case sensitive, and you're not matching a regex across multiple lines (thanks to @stribizhev for spotting that).

Use:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, "(?im)"+ expresss,
  RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
```

I can't tell from the context, but it might also be worth considering whether using `RegexOptions.CultureInvariant` is also appropriate.

EDIT: Ok, I had no idea C# could use (?im) for case + multi-line matching. In that case, not sure how this worked for you, if (?im) didn't. I just took the options off my test, leaving the (?im) on and it did match.

Comment: `(?im)` = `RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Comment: `(?im)` doesn't work in .NET, Flynn is correct that he needs to specify these as parameters to the Matches.

Comment: actually i new it was related to multiline . but iwasnt able to figure out.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I just tested it, and it did. Possibly different version of .NET? I was targetting .NET 3.5

Comment: @Flynn1179 I was wrong.  It happens sometimes... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Yeah, I have to admit, I'm not comfortable with this answer being accepted, it doesn't seem like this should have solved the problem. Certainly the `(?im)` on the front as well as the regex options should be redundant.