# Reading text between 2 html tags in xml file

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to read text between 2 html tags in a xml file. It works fine for small content but when the content is huge it fails and returns empty. What may be the is issue at a high level

```
  Regex regex = new Regex("<strong>(.*)</strong>");
      var v = regex.Match("Unneeded text <strong>Needed Text</strong> More unneeded text");
      string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: I've added the regex tag because thats what you're using, but as the tag description says " If there is a parser for it, use that instead."

Comment: _"when the content is huge"_ is not a proper [mcve]. Either create an example that reproduces the problem (hint: the `</strong>` is most likely absent) or just resort to a proper HTML parser.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14611495/1324033)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.  I suspect with large text you have \n between the tags.  I also added `.*?` in case you have multiple pairs of tags in your data.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<strong>(.*?)</strong>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

> Singleline     Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot
>   (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except
>   \n). [RegexOptions Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and it worked. Thanks for your time and suggestions

```
        var filePath = @"D:\myfile.xml";
        var fileData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(fileData);

        foreach (XElement hashElement in doc.Descendants("mytagname"))
        {
            string hashValue = (string)hashElement;
        }
```